# DotNetCore MVC Using asp-append-version="true" in an Area

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, query-string

I have a web application that makes use of a number of Areas to hold various sections.

Each area makes use of a unique "_layout.cshtml" view.

I have realised that when pages in these areas are rendered the asp-append-version="true" attribute usually added to the css and javascript link/script tags is not rendering the querystring at the end of the href/src.

I believe this is because these pages are not being served as static files - correct me if I'm wrong.

This is the code in the Configure part of my Startup class

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
   OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
   {
      const int durationInSeconds = 31536000;
      context.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "must-revalidate,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
    }
});
```

And I suspect that I need to add something here, but I don't know what!?
How do I get the rendered pages in these areas to append the querystring in the same way it does in the main application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've enabled Taghelpers in your Area With a _ViewImports.cshtml Page :

```
@using your webapp name
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

When you create a new MVC app, it would be added to your main app by default,if you add an area,don't forgot to enable it manually.

It works well in my case now:

[image]
[image]

You  could also enable the taghelper in  page with

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

for more details,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Perfect and much more straightforward than I was envisaging. Thank you.